# Chop last character of string

Tags: ruby, while-loop, chop

I want to make program which takes the string and chop last character each time and print result to console:

With an input string of `Hello`, the result should be:

```
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
```

This is my code so far:

```
def test_string
  puts "Put your string in: "
  string = gets.chomp


  while string.length == 0
    puts string.chop(/.$/)
  end


 end

 puts test_string
```

Comment: Your premise is wrong: `while string.length == 0` means _"as long as string has zero length"_ so the loop is never executed. You want `while string.length != 0` or `until string.length == 0` or more succinct `until string.empty?`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`chop!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chop%21):

```
string = gets.chomp

# Print full string, e.g. "Hello"
puts string

# Print remaining... e.g. "Hell", "Hel", etc.
while string.length != 0
  puts string.chop!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code does not modify the original string

```
string = gets.chomp
l = string.length
l.times do |i|
  puts string[0..(l-i-1)]
end
```

Comment: You can pass a _negative_ index to `[]`, thus avoiding the temporary variable: `string.length.times { |i| puts string[0..-i-1] }`. Or use `downto` for a descending loop: `string.length.downto(1) { |l| puts string[0, l] }`

Answer (score 2):

You can also create an array filling it with the string N times, and for each time, get a character less from it:

```
str = 'Hello'
Array.new(str.size) { |index| str[0...str.size - index] }.each { |str| p str }
# "Hello"
# "Hell"
# "Hel"
# "He"
# "H
```

Comment: You can avoid the trailing `each` and put the `p` inside your first block `Array.new(str.size) { |index| p str[0...str.size - index] }`.